# How to generate a comma seperated list and iterate the list into API field from dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, api-design

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id          tags
1           [independent_press,ball]
```

I am using [this](https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_edit) API call to update a contact with a particular tag. However I want to push in all the tags into the contact.

The documentation says I can pass in multiple comma separated tags.How do I do this with the list in the tags column? The code needs to also be flexible because sometimes there will be only one value in the tags column not in a list like below and other times there will be multiple values in a list but always in a list format as above.

```
id          tags
1            a
```

this is my API call so far with the df:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        params = {
            'id': row['id'],
            'p[20]*': 20,
            'status[123]':1,
            'tags':row['tags'],
            }
        resp = r.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
        print(resp)
        print(resp.text)
```

Comment: `','.join(row['tags'])`

Comment: @coldspeed the above code is parsing every letter and symbol from my tags like so(updating question):

'i,n,d,e,p,e,n,d,e,n,t,_,p,r,e,s,s'

Comment: try it with F-Strings, its very handy. (Python 3.6+)
like 

    id = row["id"]
    anyvalue = "anyvalue"
    params = f"id={id},nextvalue{anyvalue}"

Comment: @DevSepp never heard of them checking it out. thank you. Could you also give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with F-Strings, its very handy. (Python 3.6+)
like:

```
id = row["id"]
anyvalue = "anyvalue"
params = f"id={id},nextvalue={anyvalue}"
```